# How to simplify a simple loop in Javascript?

Tags: for-loop

I am now trying it out for a while and get it perfect. I am trying to simplify this *for loop* I created and make it actually work, without any arrays and only the most basic of basic JavaScript.

```
for (var x=0;x<=1;x++) { 
    if (secondInput == luckyNumber || secondInput == luckyNumber2 || secondInput == luckyNumber3) { 
        if (thirdInput == luckyNumber || thirdInput == luckyNumber2 || thirdInput == luckyNumber3) {
            if (firstInput == luckyNumber || firstInput == luckyNumber2 || firstInput == luckyNumber3) {
                while (firstInput !== secondInput){
                    while(firstInput !== thirdInput){while(secondInput !== thirdInput) {
                        alert('Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1,000!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this code make sense or am I doing something wrong? I've got the feeling that I can even leave the loop out, but it is the only way how I think it is correct.

Comment: how do you break from inner `while()` loops?

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that takes the input, compares it to the lucky numbers and returns a boolean with the result.

Call that function in your `if` clauses.

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with the `while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this idea to help:

```
[1, 3, 2].sort()
```

(store your questions and answers in arrays, and sort both then compare. Of course, checking javascript arrays for equality is a fun new project :) )

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You said you wanted it simplified.

```
for (var x = 0; 1 >= x; x++) {
if (!(secondInput != luckyNumber && secondInput != luckyNumber2 && secondInput != luckyNumber3 || thirdInput != luckyNumber && thirdInput != luckyNumber2 && thirdInput != luckyNumber3 || firstInput != luckyNumber && firstInput != luckyNumber2 && firstInput != luckyNumber3)) {
    while (firstInput !== secondInput) {
        while (firstInput !== thirdInput) {
            while (secondInput !== thirdInput) {
                alert("Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1,000!");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```